# how to enable the button if json response is true?

Tags: vue.js

I am doing a registration and my html code is

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="step1">
  <form method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
    <!-- DATA COMES HERE -->
    <div class="wizard-footer">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary' name='next' value='Next'>Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="step2">
  <!--******8data**** -->
  <button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary' name='next' value='Next'>Next</button>
</div>
```

`btn-next` is making to move to the next tab. If I remove `btn-next`, It will not move to the next tab.

My vue js code is

```
submitBox = new Vue({
  el: "#submitBox",
  data: {
    -- -- -
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;
      data = {};
      -- -- -- -- -- --
      $.ajax({
        url: '/add/post/',
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e) {
          if (e.status) {
            alert("Success")
            vm.pid = e.pid;
            console.log(vm.pid);

          } else {
            vm.response = e;

            alert(" Failed")
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
    }
  },
});
```

If e.status, then only I need to move to another tab. But now, if alert is failed also, I am going to another tab. How can I able to solve this issue. Please help me to have a solution for the same.

Comment: Can you make a live demo of this ? Happy new year.

Comment: is there any way without live demo, sice the backend requires many authentications and id's

Comment: Do you want btn-next to be enabled if you get the pid?

Comment: if status is true.. I need to enable sir

Comment: are you using bootstrap? (version?) (jqueryui?)

Comment: yes......................

Comment: can you share logic for making move to next tab. "btn-next is making to move to the next tab", so i will write working example for you.

Comment: if json response is status true, then I need to move to another tab, otherwise ie status=false don't go to next tab

Answer (score 2):

I hope i got your question right.

First, you don't need the onSubmit, you can use [modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers):

```
//REPLACE THIS
 <form method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">

//WITH THIS, NOTE THE 'prevent' MODIFIER
 <form method="POST" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit($event);">
```

Now, to disable/enable the button conditionally, just add a :disabled dynamic property:

```
//I'm assuming that if you got the pid it is considered a success,
// obviously you can change it to be any property you like as long it has a true/false value
<button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary' name='next' value='Next' :disabled="!pid">Next</button>
```

Comment: sir, in this case. how to I submit

Comment: How did you submit till now?

Comment: because here button is disabled

Comment: Like i said, this is just an example on how to dynamically enable/disable the button, you can set your own logic as to when to enable/disable it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean data:

```
data: {
  // ...
  toggleButton: false
},
```

Now, after you get successful response, just set `toggleButton` to `true`:

```
if (e.status === 200) {
  vm.toggleButton = true;
}
```

Now, in your button html, set the `toggbleButton` class:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="next" 
value="Next" :class="{ 'btn-next': toggleButton }">Next</button>
```